# Got offer letter with letterhead 9/13, submitted counter offer two days later, no reply since. How to followup?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation, counter-offer

I've been speaking to the hiring manager since the beginning since their recruiter was too busy, and it's been great. She has a great understanding of my background and where I want to go.

She mentioned she's offering me the high band (in the top 25%) where they usually offer the lower 50% band to juniors like me. It's because I sold my business a few months ago.

I received an offer letter over email with the letterhead and all, and asked for top of the band (8% salary increase).

I haven't heard back.

I was prepared to accept her original offer if she said this was too much.
But now I'm worried I lost the offer. I do need the job.

I don't want to seem desperate. But I do want to communicate I'll take the original offer.

In this position, when's a good time to followup and what is a reasonable way to communicate the above?

Comment: @sf02 Typo, fixed, thanks for pointing it out. Blame my 2018 MacBook keyboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat no unfortunately, as I'm wondering about the delicate nature of a post-offer counteroffer followup situation rather than a pre-offer followup.

Comment: Here is the link to all interesting questions and answers about **Counter Offer** on this forum (SE WorkPlace): https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=Counter+Offer. You will find all possible scenarios and real-life responses from companies when job applicants make the **Counter Offers** .

Comment: "In this position, when's a good time to followup and what is a reasonable way to communicate the above?" This is a negotiation. If you want to fold now, fold. No one else can make that call for you. No one knows what they're thinking. Maybe they'll be able to find someone else, or maybe they won't. But if you want to fold now, I'd give them a phone call if I were you.

Comment: @John there's no delicate anything.  If you haven't heard for a week, just send a simple "Howdy, any news" message.  (Forget about the "counter-offer" one way or the other.)

Answer (score 6):

You haven't heard in a week.

Simply **send a follow-up.**

Don't even mention your "counter-offer". It's irrelevant.

Hence,

> Cheers Steve, any news on the XYZ position?

Be aware that it's 95% likely they happened to choose someone else and/or the position is gone.

Comment: You can also call, use a phone, email is to easily ignored